# active admin: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am having a problem with active admin. I am getting the following issue,
`` undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass `` around the line `insert_tag renderer_for(:index)`

I googled for the issue. Some suggested to pull the activeadmin from master branch. I tried it too.
I updated the gemfile as: 
`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'`
But this didn't helped me too. The issue was same.

I am using `rails 4.0.4`

Please can someone help me with this issue.

Comment: Does stacktrace showing line number of error? If yes, then you can try adding debugger in gem file before that line number that helps to solve problem

Comment: Have you registered that 'name' field with ActiveAdmin and added it to permit_params list?

Comment: Post your activeadmin generated model please

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar I am having this problem only in production. The same thing is working well in the development environment.

Comment: did you run all migrations on production?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yes I did, But the issue is same.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. `name` field seems to be empty in database. That's the reason for runtime error. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling through the code, I found out that at some point the `name` field was empty in database. And this was causing the problem.

Not a active-admin issue. :)